# GWT - How to programmatically uncheck a CheckboxCell when another CheckboxCell is checked?

Tags: java, user-interface, checkbox, gwt, celltable

Given two `CheckboxCell`'s *checkboxA* and *checkboxB*, how can I programmatically uncheck checkboxB if checkboxA is unchecked? From what I've tried, I'm able to set the value of `checkboxB = false` when `checkboxA = false`, but this change is not being reflected in the UI.

My table with the checkboxes -

```
public void buildTable() {
    myDataProvider.addDataDisplay(myTable);

    // other columns

    Column<Note, Boolean> checkboxA = new Column<Note, Boolean>(new CheckboxCell()){

        @Override
        public Boolean getValue(Note object) {
            return object.isAChecked();
        }

    };

    checkboxA.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Note, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void update(int index, Note object, Boolean value) {
            performCheckboxAOperation(object, value);
        }
    });

    Column<Note, Boolean> checkboxB = new Column<Note, Boolean>(new CheckboxCell()){

        @Override
        public Boolean getValue(Note object) {
            return object.isBChecked();
        }

    };

    checkboxB.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Note, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void update(int index, Note object, Boolean value) {
            performCheckboxBOperation(object, value);
        }
    });

    myTable.addColumn(checkboxA, "BOX A");
    myTable.addColumn(checkboxB, "BOX B");
}
```

Method to store checkbox A's value in the DB, and if `checkboxA == false`, also set `checkboxB = false` in the DB -

```
public void performCheckboxAOperation(Note note, Boolean bool) {
    this.presenter.performBoxOperation(note, bool, new AsyncCallback<CNote>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // error logic
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CompanyNote result) {
            cleanupDataProvider.flush();

            if (result.isAChecked() == false) {
                if (result.isBChecked() == true) {
                    unsetB(result);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is my method to unset checkboxB which is changing the value in the DB but not in the UI -

```
private void unsetB(Note note) {
    this.presenter.performBoxOperation(note, false, new AsyncCallback<Note>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // error logic
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Note result) {
            myDataProvider.flush();
            myTable.redraw();
        }
    });
}
```

From what I understand, *ListDataProvider* needs to be flushed for the changes to be reflected in the UI. This has worked very well for all the other fields in the table, but it is not working with CheckboxCells.

I've already tried to `redraw()` the table as can be seen above but without any luck.

So what should I be doing to trigger a UI change in another CheckboxCell when one CheckboxCell is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you forgot to actually change the object's value.

```
private void unsetB(final Note note) {
    this.presenter.performBoxOperation(note, false, new AsyncCallback<Note>() {
        // ...
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Note result) {
            note.setB(false);  // set B value or copy `result` to `note`
                               // (`note` must be final)
            myDataProvider.flush();
            myTable.redraw();
        }
    });
}
```

Also, in `performCheckboxAOperation` you call `unsetB(result);` - it should be `unsetB(note);`

You need to understand that in `onSuccess` you get a copy of `Note`. The `result` object is not in the `DataProvider`, `note` is. And you should change `note`'s value.

Comment: I am changing the object's value. As stated above, `this.presenter.performBoxOperation(note, false, new AsyncCallback<Note>()`, sets the object's value to `false` on the server, stores it in the DB, and then returns `Note` with the change. When I step-through `myDataProvider` inside `onSuccess()`, I can see that `checkboxB = false`. So the value is being changed but not being reflected in the UI by unchecking the checkbox, even after flushing the data provider and redrawing the table. I tried making `note` final and calling `unsetB(note)`, which weirdly worked once and then never again.

Comment: Whenever you send an object to/from the server it is serialized and deserialized, which simply means that you make a _copy_ of that object. So you take an object, make a copy and update a copy,

Comment: Thanks for this. Your answer and the comment helped me debug the issue. I had to replace the `'note` in `myDataProvider` with `result` and then `flush()` for the changed to get reflected. So, `myDataProvider.getList().set(myDataProvider.getList().indexOf(note), result); myDataProvider.flush();`.